# Get date+time timestamp

Tags: php, javascript

I need a timestamp code similar to this JavaScript code:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

I tried this PHP code:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$ts = $date->getTimestamp();
```

which returns `1376399143` but the JavaScript code returns `1376399143263`, I think my PHP code generates a timestamp for only the date. How can I get the timestamp for the time portion as well?

Comment: The javascript ts is miliseconds, the php one is in seconds.

Comment: how can i get the milliseconds as well in php ?

Comment: Probably be easier to just divide the javascript timestamp by 1000.

Comment: no i dont use javascript code at all , only php

Comment: @AnishaVirat http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the code below

```
$time = mktime(date("H"),date("i"),date("s"),date("n"),date("j"),date("Y"));
echo $time;
```

for details information on **mktime** , check [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php), but if you do not need the additional precision (which will get lost because of networking), just divide the javascript time by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `microtime`

```
$seconds = microtime(true); // false = int, true = float 
echo round(($seconds * 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

The php code generates the timestamp for date and time, but it returns the number of **seconds** from 1-1-1970. Javascript returns the value in **miliseconds**.

You could use `microtime(true)*1000;` for a similar result that Javascript.